# Página demorando para carregar

Tags: php, datatable

Eu tenho uma tabela que vai listar dados, porém são MUITOS dados, o que está levando muito tempo para a página carregar.

Como eu faço para evitar esse problema?

Exemplo: Que os itens da tabela vão aparecendo de acordo com a barra de rolagem.

Pesquisando achei isso: https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side , porém não entendi como aplicar, alguém pode me ajudar? aqui está o código:

```
                       $sql = "SELECT * FROM item_db ORDER BY id ASC";
                        $sql = $pdo->query($sql);

                        include "functions/tipo_itens.php";
                        include "functions/equipa_em.php";

                         foreach ($sql->fetchAll() as $row) {

                            $id = $row['id'];

                            $tipo = $row['type'];

                            $equipa = $row['equip_locations'];



                            ?>

                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo "<img src='./images/db_itens/icons/$id.png'> ".$row['id'].""; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['name_japanese']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $tipo_itens[$tipo]; ?></td>
                                <td>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mediumModal<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">Visualizar</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <!-- Inicio Modal -->
                            <div class="modal fade" id="mediumModal<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mediumModalLabel">
                                <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="mediumModalLabel"><?php echo "<img src='./images/db_itens/images/$id.png'> #".$row['id']." - ".$row['name_japanese'].""; ?></h5>
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            

                                            <p> <b>Nome:</b> <?php echo $row['name_japanese']; ?></p>
                                            <p> <b>Tipo:</b> <?php echo $tipo_itens[$tipo]; ?></p>
                                            <p> <b>Valor de Compra:</b> <?php echo $row['price_buy']; ?></p>
                                            <p> <b>Valor de Venda:</b> <?php echo $row['price_sell']; ?></p>
                                            <p> <b>Peso:</b> <?php echo $row['weight']; ?></p>
                                            <p> <b>Defesa:</b> <?php echo $row['defence']; ?></p>
                                            <p> <b>ATK/MATK:</b> <?php echo "".$row['atk']."/".$row['atk'].""; ?></p>
                                            <p> <b>Nível da Arma:</b> <?php echo $row['weapon_level']; ?></p>
                                            <p> <b>Distância:</b> <?php echo $row['range']; ?></p>
                                            <p> <b>Slots:</b> <?php echo $row['slots']; ?></p>
                                            <p> <b>Nível Mínimo para Equipar:</b> <?php echo $row['equip_level_min']; ?></p>
                                            <p> <b>Equipa em:</b> <?php echo $equipa_em[$equipa]; ?></p>
                                            <p> <b>Script ao usar:</b> <?php echo $row['script']; ?></p>
                                            <p> <b>Script ao equipar:</b> <?php echo $row['equip_script']; ?></p>
                                            <p> <b>Script ao desequipar:</b> <?php echo $row['unequip_script']; ?></p>

                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Fim Modal -->
                        <?php } ?>
```

Comment: eu faço isso carregando apenas os dados visíveis da página e usando o append com o ajax para carregar mais dados conforme o usuário desça a barra de rolagem

Answer (score -2):

Você precisa limitar a quantidade de linhas da sua tabela.

Existem diversas maneiras de resolver.

- Adicionando algum filtro para não listar tantos dados;
- Limitar a quantidade de linhas
- Fazer chamadas assíncronas com JavaScript para ir preenchendo a tabela aos poucos conforme a navegação do usuário

Comment: Então, como eu faço esse tipo de filtro? A tabela já carrega 20 itens por página, porém a página só carrega quando ela lista os itens de todas as páginas.

Comment: @RafaelRenan Você não precisa consultar todos os itens de uma só vez, você deve consultar sob demanda, utilizando em sua query um **Skip/Take**, para que não traga a massa de dados inteira para a memória. Você pode também ver a criação de um **índice** para sua consulta, isso tornará mais veloz.